# Imgenes en bases de datos y Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Buenas noches vengo trabajando con Laravel 5.6, y me dieron la tarea de hacer una consulta a la base de datos que es postgresql y mostrar el resultado en una vista. El problema esta, en que entre los datos consultados hay un campo donde se almacena imágenes y esta en formato bytea, y al tratar de pasar el dato hacia la vista laravel me responde:
    Type is not supported

este es el código que tengo en el controlador:

```
public function Datosfull($id,$gestion){
        $Datofuncionario = DB::connection($gestion)->table('funcionario')
                  ->select('id_funcionario','nombre','apellido','celular','fecha_ingreso')
                    ->where('id_funcionario','=',$id)
                    ->first();
       $fotografia = DB::connection($gestion)->table('fotografia')
                    ->select('id_tipo_fotografia','nombre')
                    ->where('id_funcionario','=',$Datofuncionario->id_funcionario) ->get();
return view('inspector.funcionario',compact('Datofuncionario','fotografia'));
```

Como debo hacer para que estos datos pasen a la vista y que las fotografias se decodifiquen y puedan ser visualizadas.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo uso de pg_unescape_bytea podrías convertir a string tu bytea, así:

```
$tipo_string = pg_unescape_bytea($bytea);
```

Sin embargo, como lo tienes ahora, ten en cuenta de que en $Datofuncionario obtienes un array y en $fotografia una colección.

La variable $tipo_string es la que pasarías a la vista:

```
return view('inspector.funcionario',compact('tipo_string'));
```

En la vista, otra conversión:

```
{{ htmlspecialchars($tipo_string)}};
```

Comment: Hice lo que me indicaste pero me responde lo siguiente 'Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\pg_unescape_bytea()'

Comment: Es una función nativa de php, aquí su documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-unescape-bytea.php. Te animo a que veas la documentación, ya que hay ejemplos. Un saludo